# PCA in R... subjects columns and observations are rows?

Tags: r

Okay so I'm very new to R and have no real clue what I'm doing (be patient with me).
I'm trying to do a PCA and my data consists of behavioural observations from 6 individuals in which I measured 18 behaviours at different times.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SApcD.png)
To do a PCA in R do I have to have my subjects as columns and my behaivours as rows or what? How does it read it? This is probably a really stupid question... sorry!

Comment: Please consider giving us some sample data with `dput()`. Also have you taken a look at links like this? https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pca-analysis-r . My guess would be the 18 behaviors are rows and the 6 individuals are columns as the behaviors happen at different time points.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to learn. Do you want to identify people who participate in similar activities or do you want to identify activities that are common across people? Both are reasonable, but different, questions.